# SSD with Linux installed onto it does not show up as a Device in Explorer

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-explorer

I have two identical SSDs, both 128 GB. The first has Linux, Deepin to be exact. The second is a freshly installed Windows 10. Inside Windows 10 File Explorer, I cannot see the Linux HDD, only the current Windows SSD I booted into. 
[image]

I can, however, see the first Linux HDD in diskmgmt.msc. It displays as shown:

[image]

Disk 0: Deepin Linux (uses [Nautilus](http://appstore.deepin.org/app/nautilus).)

Disk 1: Windows 10 (Uses explorer.exe)

**Is there a way to display and access the hidden SSD without any formatting or resetting the SSD so that I do not lose my files on my Linux HDD?**

Comment: What is the filesystem on the Linux partition?

Comment: Deepin uses [Nautilus](http://appstore.deepin.org/app/nautilus).

Comment: Nautilus is a file manager, not a [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem).

Comment: Nautilus is a file manager, it's irrelevant. A filesystem for Linux may be ext4 or btrfs or something else. Your Windows uses NTFS; it understands NTFS and various types of FAT. It's uncommon (and rather hard) to install Linux on a filesytem that Windows can read without third party programs. Probably this is why you cannot access your Linux files from Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows cannot read Linux file systems natively, that's why all you see is the partition.

Depending on the the type of file system, there are [3rd party software products](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20ext4&oq=windows%20ext&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i61j0l3.7109j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that can read Linux file systems.

Answer (score -2):

You can access the Linux partition from Windows by adding a drive letter to the volume (which is analogous to mounting the partition):

1. Open Disk Management
2. Right-click the volume and choose **Change drive letters and paths...**
3. Click **Add...**
4. Select the **Assign the following drive letter:** radio button then choose a drive letter from the drop down list.
5. Click OK twice to save your changes.

Whether you can actually *interact* with the files on the partition depends on what type of [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) it uses.

Comment: This will not work.  Windows cannot assign a drive letter to a filesystem it cannot read.

Comment: As in, it won't assign a drive letter, or it won't automagically make Windows able to read the target filesystem?

Comment: neither will work

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid your correct if the filesystem isn't readable by Windows.

Comment: I need 2 more downvotes so I can get the [Peer Pressure](https://superuser.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure) badge.  LOL.